# Fixed point stability of non-linear ode system

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory

Suppose, I have a system of 4 coupled non-linear ode in 4 variables(2 variables are from a compact space, two from non-compact space). Let $\mathbf{x}_0$ be a fixed point of the system. Now, I want to determine the stability of the system at the fixed point $\mathbf{x}_0$.

I used linearization to find the local Jacobian of the stability matrix and determined its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I have two cases:

1. All four eigenvalues are zero and the eigenspace is of dimension 2
2. Two eigenvalues are zero and the rest two are purely imaginary conjuagte pairs. The geometric multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue is 1

Thus in both cases I have geometric multiplicity< algebraic multiplicity for the zero eigenvalue.

Can I then conclude that my fixed point is unstable?

Comment: Using your method, are these systems stable, unstable or something inbetween: $\left\{ \begin{aligned} &\dot{x} = y +x^5  \\ &\dot{y} = -x + y^3 \end{aligned}\right.$ and $\left\{ \begin{aligned} &\dot{x} = y - x^5  \\ &\dot{y} = -x - y^3 \end{aligned}\right.$? At the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Zeekless The eigenvalues are purely imaginary with algebraic multiplicity=geometric multiplicity and hence fixed point (0,0) is neutral.

Comment: Well, it is not. Those terms, which you "throw away" when linearizing, play a crucial rule in this case.

Comment: @ Zeekless What is a better way to analyze such systems?

Comment: @ Subho95, at first you should linearize them (as you did). But if you get all eigenvalues with zero real parts, then you have to try something else. Lyapunov function is always the answer:) In the example that I gave you, the function $V = x^2+y^2$ will help you to get the right answer in both cases.

Comment: @Zeekless If there is a neutral fixed point, then what you are saying is probably correct. If the claim is that the fixed point is unstable from the linearization analysis, I think it will persist even for the original ode system.

Comment: @ Subho95, sure, it will. You only have to be careful with "neutral" types after linearization. And this is exactly your case in the question.

Comment: @Zeekless I had made a mistake. Please check my claim is that it's unstable.

Comment: @ Subho95, what would you claim about $\left\{ \begin{aligned} &\dot{x} = -x^5  \\ &\dot{y} = -y^3 \end{aligned}\right. $ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80315/discussion-between-subho95-and-zeekless).